# How can we not write a program to use a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, api, curl

When I hear API, I think the only way to use an API is to write a program to call the functions provided by the API.

Is writing a program the only way of using a RESTful API?

It seems that we can use `curl` to use RESTful API in https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/. So how is that possible without writing a program to call the functions provided by a RESTful API?

Thanks.

Comment: You can invoke an HTTP API in your browser and get back the response.  For example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't invoke a RESTful API via a utility such as curl.

However, it only works for the simplest of use cases.

Most use cases have several steps that simply work better through automation. From creating or interpreting the payloads that are sent/received from the API calls, to orchestrating several calls in a larger transaction.

Also, consider, if you put your curl command in to a script file, then, well, that's "programming".

Comment: Thanks. when using curl, what actually directly calls the functions defined in a RESTful API?